# Spring Data Rest Search by Example Entity

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

Does Spring Data Rest support the JPARepository's method below?

```
<S extends T> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable);
```

Or any variants of find by Example entity in `QueryByExampleExecutor`?